# The cd dvd boot option isn't showing up in bios

Tags: boot, 13.10, dvd, bios

I am trying to dual boot ubuntu 13.10 but the option for it isn't in the bios. I did previously install ubuntu on my computer and tried to delete it but it didnt work. What do i do?

Comment: Can you offer some additional information?  Who's your computer's manufacturer?  How did you burn the install medium?  Has this particular install medium shown up before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also prepare an Ubuntu live USB for installing Ubuntu and boot from that. You will need a USB flash drive that is 2GB or larger. For Ubuntu 18.04 and later the USB flash drive should be 4GB or larger. In the BIOS menu, you need to change the boot order so that the USB flash drive, which is usually called USB-HDD in newer computers, is the first entry in the boot sequence, and then save your new BIOS settings and exit the BIOS setup.

The instructions for preparing an Ubuntu live USB on Windows are found at the official Ubuntu [How to create a bootable USB stick...](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows) webpage (see the step-by-step instructions below).

1. Open Rufus and select your USB stick in the *Device* dropdown menu.

   [image]
2. Click the CD-ROM icon next to the *FreeDOS* dropdown menu, then find your downloaded Ubuntu ISO and click *Open* and then *Start*.

   [image]
3. Click *Yes* when it asks to download Syslinux software.

   [image]
4. Click *OK* to write in ISO Image mode.

   [image]
5. Confirm that your USB stick is selected and then click *OK* to continue. It is **very important** to verify that the device that you are installing the Ubuntu live USB to is indeed your flash drive, so that you don't overwrite any of your system or personal files which may make your operating system unbootable.

   [image]
6. When it is finished, just restart your computer and start using Ubuntu, or you can install Ubuntu.

   [image]

Answer (score 0):

If you mean option for DVD player in bios, I would say the bios couldn't see DVD player, you can check hardware connection or try UEFI bios if you have this function on your bios.

Correct me if I'm wrong. Thanks.